# std::vector::size with glDrawElements crashes?

Tags: c++, vector, obj

`( win32 / OpenGL 3.3 / GLSL 330 )`

I decided after a long time of trying to do a graphical user interface using just opengl graphics to go back to a gui toolkit and so in the process have had to port alot of my code to `win32`.

But I have a problem with my `glDrawElement` function.

my program compiles and runs fine until it gets to glDrawElements then crashes.. which is rather annoying right.

so I was trying to figure out why and I found out its std::vector::size member not returning the correct amount of faces in the unsigned interger vector eg, "`vector<unsigned int>faces;` "

so when I use `cout << faces.size() << endl;`

*I got 68 elements????*

instead of `24` as you can see here in this `.obj file:`

```
# Blender v2.61 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -0.999999
v 0.999999 1.000000 1.000001
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
s off
f 1 2 3 4     
f 5 8 7 6     
f 1 5 6 2    
f 2 6 7 3     <--- 24 Faces not 68?
f 3 7 8 4     
f 5 1 4 8
```

I'm using a parser I created to get the `faces/vertexes` in my `.obj file:`

```
  char modelbuffer [20000];
  int MAX_BUFF = 20000;
  unsigned int face[3];

   FILE * pfile;

   pfile = fopen(szFileName,  "rw");

   while(fgets(modelbuffer,  MAX_BUFF, pfile) != NULL)
   {              
   if('v')
      {
        Point p;

        sscanf(modelbuffer, "v %f %f %f",  &p.x, &p.y, &p.z);

        points.push_back(p);

        cout << " p.x = " << p.x << " p.y = " << p.y << " p.z = " << p.x << endl;
      }

    if('f')
      {

      sscanf(modelbuffer, "f %d %d %d %d", &face[0], &face[1], &face[2],  &face[3]);         

         cout << "face[0] = " << face[0] << " face[1] = " << face[1] << " face[2] = " << face[2] << " face[3] = " << face[3] << "\n";

          faces.push_back(face[0] - 1);
          faces.push_back(face[1] - 1);
          faces.push_back(face[2] - 1);
          faces.push_back(face[3] - 1);
          cout << face[0] - 1 << face[1] - 1 << face[2] - 1 << face[3] - 1 << endl;        
      }     
   }
```

using this struct to store the x,y,z positions also this vector was used with Point:

```
vector<Point>points;

struct Point 
{

float x,  y, z;

};
```

If someone could tell me why its not working and how to fix it that would be awesome I also provide a pastebin to the full source code if you want a closer look.

```
http://pastebin.com/gznYLVw7
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is in the parser. The code after the lines if('v') and if('f') always enter those branches (you're basically saying if(true) two times). So your code basically pushes something back into the vector every time the loop executes (I think this is basically once for every line in your file? I'm bad with C functions).

I think you mean to say something like

```
if(modelbuffer[currentindex] == 'v')
```

etc.

As a bonus, since you're using vector I'm strongly assuming that you have access to a C++ compiler. Please use std::ifstream and getline. Thanks :-)

Comment: my char variable doesn't have a member called current index :P how would I get one lol EDIT: tried using ifstream but could not find a better way to loop through the hole file finding the v/f unless I would use eof but thats error prone due to a flag set

Comment: Well, define and initialize the variable outside your loop (unsigned int currentindex = 0) and increment it by whatever amount of chars fgets() reads. I don't know how to determine that, with fgets, though. I would use std::ifstream and save all the lines that youre reading into a vector of std::string, which makes operating on these things a lot easier.

Comment: Is that eof() error chance really relevant to your project? Are you somehow operating in an environment where eof() is wrong a lot?

Comment: not really shore just didn't want to take a risk with it but I guess it could work for now. :) I already got code to do it so it won't be very hard to get it to work thank god.

Comment: Well, you don't have to call me god just for that. But you can accept my answer and upvote it

Comment: lol :P I will defently up vote ofc

Comment: before you go one more it glDrawElement still crashes when I use GL_UNSIGNED_INT ? have you experienced this before and could give me help with this ??.

Comment: mhm.. Can you post your glDrawElement code into pastebin and click the little tick under the upvote button to my answer? :P

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JpbjexbR if you need anything just ask :) - heres a better one http://pastebin.com/BsfsfrvZ :)

Comment: I don't know why that crashes, but do you realize that there's a special function in OpenGL for drawing buffers? glDrawBuffer

Comment: yep now I do. :)

Comment: @heishe: [`glDrawBuffer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawBuffer) does not *draw* anything; it sets the current draw buffer. It says which image in the framebuffer will be the render target.